# logistic regression with random intercepts with optim in R

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression

I am trying to estimate a `logistic regression` model with `random intercepts` using `optim` in `R`.  I have not been able to locate any example code for using random effects with `optim` and am not sure whether it is possible.  However, I assume it is.  My `R` code is below.  However, my code does not seem to be performing extremely well.  Can someone please suggest where I might be making a mistake?  My point estimates do not look too bad.  However, my estimated SE's do not look good.  One is even `NaN`.

First I generate some fake data using five intercepts randomly assigned to 1000 observations.

```
#install.packages('arm')
library(arm)  # Gelman and Hill R package

# Generate some data
set.seed(1234)
n        <- 1000                                  # number of observations
groups   <- 1:5                                   # groups for random intercepts
my.obs   <- sample(groups, n, replace = TRUE)     # assign group to each observation
my.cov   <- rnorm(n, mean = 0.30, sd = 0.05)      # create covariate data

mu.a     <- 0.30                                  # mean for random intercepts
sigma.a  <- 0.10                                  # SD for random intercepts
B0       <- rnorm(length(groups), mu.a, sigma.a)  # value of random intercept for each group
B1       <- 0.45                                  # covariate slope
my.inter <- B0[my.obs]                            # value of intercept for each observation
lin.pred <- B0[my.obs] + B1 * my.cov              # linear predictor for each observation

logit.p  <- exp(lin.pred) / (1 + exp(lin.pred))   # probability for each observation
y        <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob=logit.p)       # simulate random outcome of model
```

I analyze those data first using a `logistic regression` model with `fixed intercepts`:

```
# analyze using logistic regression with fixed intercepts
mylogit  <- glm(y ~ my.cov, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit)
```

The estimate of the slope on the covariate (0.2947) is not particularly close to the true value (0.45).

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.2670     0.3962   0.674     0.50
my.cov        0.2947     1.2988   0.227     0.82
```

Then I analyze those data using `logistic regression` with `random intercepts` using `package arm`:

```
my.obs   <- as.factor(my.obs)
my.model <- glmer (y ~ my.cov + (1 | my.obs), family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(my.model)

# extract estimated coefficients
fixed.effects  <- fixef(my.model)
fixed.effects

random.effects <- ranef(my.model)
random.effects

my.coef <- coef(my.model)  # (fixed + random intercepts)
my.coef
#$my.obs
#  (Intercept)    my.cov
#1   0.1683482 0.2352318
#2   0.3502571 0.2352318
#3   0.4548216 0.2352318
#4   0.2937610 0.2352318
#5   0.1377921 0.2352318

my.est.intercepts <- (as.numeric(fixed.effects[1]) + 
                      as.numeric(unlist(random.effects$my.obs)))
my.est.intercepts
#[1] 0.1683482 0.3502571 0.4548216 0.2937610 0.1377921

# true intercepts
#[1] 0.4128684 0.2005167 0.3369223 0.2706445 0.3036248
```

Then I analyze those data using `logistic regression` with `random intercepts` using `optim`:

```
logit.negLL = function(betas, y, my.obs, my.cov) {

     b1  =  betas[1]  # mean of random intercepts
     b2  =  betas[2]  # sd of random intercepts
     b3  =  betas[3]  # covariate

     b.obs1 <- rnorm(1, b1, b2)
     b.obs2 <- rnorm(1, b1, b2)
     b.obs3 <- rnorm(1, b1, b2)
     b.obs4 <- rnorm(1, b1, b2)
     b.obs5 <- rnorm(1, b1, b2)

     llh <- rep(0,length(y))

     llh.total <- 0

     for(i in 1:length(y)) {

          if(my.obs[i] == 1) my.prob = exp(b.obs1 + b3 * my.cov[i]) / (1 + exp(b.obs1 + b3 * my.cov[i]))
          if(my.obs[i] == 2) my.prob = exp(b.obs2 + b3 * my.cov[i]) / (1 + exp(b.obs2 + b3 * my.cov[i]))
          if(my.obs[i] == 3) my.prob = exp(b.obs3 + b3 * my.cov[i]) / (1 + exp(b.obs3 + b3 * my.cov[i]))
          if(my.obs[i] == 4) my.prob = exp(b.obs4 + b3 * my.cov[i]) / (1 + exp(b.obs4 + b3 * my.cov[i]))
          if(my.obs[i] == 5) my.prob = exp(b.obs5 + b3 * my.cov[i]) / (1 + exp(b.obs5 + b3 * my.cov[i]))

          llh[i]    <- llh[i] + log(my.prob*y[i] + (1-my.prob)*(1 - y[i]))
          llh.total <- llh.total + llh[i]

     }
     -1 * llh.total
}

my.output <- optim(c(0.3, 0.1, .45), logit.negLL, y = y, my.obs = my.obs, my.cov = my.cov,
                   method="BFGS", hessian=TRUE)
#There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

# Here are my point estimates.  They do not look too bad.
R.est <- my.output$par
R.est
#[1] 0.21501634 0.02136591 0.47118554    

true.values <- c(0.30, 0.10, 0.45)

# Covariances and standard errors
covmat = solve(my.output$hessian)

# Here are my SE's.  They seem to look pretty bad.
R.SE <- diag(covmat)^0.5
R.SE
#[1]         NaN 0.001433485 0.002519182
```

Comment: Fitting GLMMs is not necessarily something you can roll yourself; I think you're very much misunderstanding how they work (you don't pick a random deviate for the intercepts - instead you *integrate* over all possible values for the conditional modes, or some approximation). You can look at https://github.com/lme4/lme4pureR/blob/master/R/pirls.R for a pure-R translation of the method that `glmer` uses (detailed description in [this directory](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/tree/master/misc/glmer_JSS))

Comment: Thank you, @BenBolker.  No doubt I am misunderstanding.  I was just more-or-less guessing, trying to do what seemed intuitive with no real basis.  I will look at the github code you posted and no doubt switch to JAGS.

Comment: The TMB package is another "roll-your-own" platform that can handle these kinds of problems. What is your ultimate goal? (Presumably you want to do something that `glmer` can't handle, *or* you're trying to understand the underlying machinery better?)

Comment: @BenBolker My ultimate goal is to create a capture-recapture model with random observer effects.  I do not think `Program MARK` will do that.  So, I thought I would start with `optim` and then go to `JAGS` if `optim` did not work.  Although, learning `TMB` is on my to-do list after hearing that `ADMB` is being phased out.

Comment: Yup. There's a section on "Hierarchical modeling frameworks" at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html ... also see https://oliviergimenez.github.io/blog/multievent_in_tmb/

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet worked through the `lme4pureR` code `Ben Bolker` mentioned.  However, I did locate `R` code for simulating `logistic regression` data with `random intercepts`.  That code is located here:

https://nhorton.people.amherst.edu/sasr2/simulation_generation.pdf

I thought I would post that code heavily annotated because simulating data correctly is a critical first step regardless of whether I ultimately analyze that data with `JAGS`, `OpenBUGS`, `Nimble`, `MARK`, `lme4pureR`, or `TMB`.  I also discovered that `MARK` can handle at least some `random effects`.

**Edit: June 19, 2023:** Added `R` code for `Bayesian logistic regression` using `JAGS` for models with: 1.) fixed intercept and one covariate, 2.) fixed intercept and three covariates, and 3.) random intercepts and three covariates.  The random intercept `JAGS` model might not be correct.

**Edit: June 21, 2023:** Added `R` code for `Bayesian logistic regression` using `JAGS` for models with random intercepts and three covariates.  This code returns estimates essentially the same as the true values.  The estimates are very similar to those returned by `glmer` in the `lme4` package.

Here is the `R` code for simulating data.  My biggest oversight in simulating the data might have been that I did not include a `fixed intercept` along with a `random intercept`.

```
# Generate some data
set.seed(1234)

# Code from: https://nhorton.people.amherst.edu/sasr2/simulation_generation.pdf

n      = 1500 
p      = 3
sigbsq = 4

# These are the true values of the fixed intercept and the slopes
beta = c(-2, 1.5, 0.5, -1)

# each id appears three times in the data set
id   = rep(1:n, each=p)
id[1:21]
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7

# x1 is an indicator variable
# The first half of the observations are in one group represented by x1.
# The second half are in a second group represented by the fixed intercept.
x1   = as.numeric(id < (n+1)/2)
table(x1)
# x1
#    0    1 
# 2250 2250
sum(x1[1:2250])
#[1] 2250
sum(x1[2251:4500])
#[1] 0

# Determine the value of the random intercept for each id.
# Must the mean = 0?
# Must sigbsq be a constant for all 4500 observations?
randint = rep(rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(sigbsq)), each=p)
randint[1:21]
#[1] -2.4141315 -2.4141315 -2.4141315
#     0.5548585  0.5548585  0.5548585
#     2.1688824  2.1688824  2.1688824
#    -4.6913954 -4.6913954 -4.6913954
#     0.8582494  0.8582494  0.8582494
#     1.0121118  1.0121118  1.0121118
#    -1.1494799 -1.1494799 -1.1494799

# The covariate x2 is 1, 2, 3 for each id.
# I do not know whether that has any special meaning.
# But I doubt it.
x2 = rep(1:p, n)
table(x2)
# x2
#   1    2    3 
# 1500 1500 1500

# The covariate x3 is just random values from 0 to 1
x3 = runif(p*n)

# There are 4500 observations in the data set
length(x1)
length(x2)
length(x3)
length(randint)

# There is a fixed intercept and a random intercept and three covariates
# The random intercept is constant for each id.
# Must it have a mean of 0?
linpred = beta[1] + beta[2]*x1 + beta[3]*x2 + beta[4]*x3 + randint

expit = exp(linpred)/(1 + exp(linpred))

y = runif(p*n) < expit              # generate a logical as our outcome

# Fit the model using the glmer() function from the lme4 package.
library(lme4)

glmmres = glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|id), family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(glmmres)
# Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
#  Family: binomial  ( logit )
# Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | id)
# 
#      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#   5222.4   5254.5  -2606.2   5212.4     4495 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.1377 -0.4912 -0.2851  0.5539  2.8469 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  id     (Intercept) 3.114    1.765   
# Number of obs: 4500, groups:  id, 1500
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -1.94548    0.16250 -11.972   <2e-16 ***
# x1           1.51867    0.13161  11.539   <2e-16 ***
# x2           0.56017    0.05115  10.951   <2e-16 ***
# x3          -1.41114    0.16063  -8.785   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#    (Intr) x1     x2    
# x1 -0.490              
# x2 -0.680  0.118       
# x3 -0.355 -0.102 -0.090

# Note that: sqrt(sigbsq) = sqrt(4) = 2
# And:
# Random effects:
#  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  id     (Intercept) 3.114    1.765 

# extract estimated coefficients
# The estimated slope for x3 is not that great.
fixed.effects  <- fixef(glmmres)
fixed.effects
# (Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
#  -1.9454788   1.5186733   0.5601717  -1.4111386
# beta = c(-2, 1.5, 0.5, -1)

random.effects <- ranef(glmmres)
head(random.effects)

my.coef <- coef(glmmres)  # (fixed + random intercepts)
dim(my.coef$id)
#[1] 1500    4
head(my.coef$id)

my.est.intercepts <- (as.numeric(fixed.effects[1]) + 
                      as.numeric(unlist(random.effects$id)))
head(my.est.intercepts)

range(my.est.intercepts - my.coef$id[,1])
#[1] 0 0
```

**EDIT - June 19, 2023**

I think I have come up with `JAGS` code for `Bayesian` models.  I create: 1.) a `logistic regression` model using one covariate and a fixed intercept with `glm` and `JAGS`, 2.) a `logistic regression` model using three covariates and a fixed intercept with `glm` and `JAGS` and 3.) a `logistic regression` model using three covariates and random intercepts with `glmer` and `JAGS`.  I am not sure the `JAGS` code with the `random intercepts` is correct, but the `fixed effect` estimates look good.  I will investigate this more and edit my answer if I locate an error.

A `logistic regression` with a `fixed intercept` and one covariate with `glm`.

```
mylogitx1  <- glm(y ~ x1, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogitx1)
# Call:
# glm(formula = y ~ x1, family = "binomial")
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -1.1729  -1.1729  -0.8098   1.1819   1.5966  
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -0.94667    0.04698  -20.15   <2e-16 ***
# x1           0.93600    0.06312   14.83   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 6012.4  on 4499  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 5785.5  on 4498  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 5789.5
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

A `logistic regression` with a `fixed intercept` and one covariate with `JAGS`.

```
library(jagsUI)             # Load jagsUI
library('lme4')             # Load lme4
library(MASS)               # Load MASS

y <- as.numeric(y)
table(y)

n <- length(y)

str(bdata <- list(y = y, x1 = x1, n = length(y)))

# Specify model in BUGS language
cat(file = "logistic_regression_x1_June19_2023b.txt","
model {

     # Priors
     alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
     beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)

     # Likelihood
     for (i in 1:n) {
          y[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 1)
          logit(p[i]) <- alpha + beta * x1[i]
     }

     # Derived quantities
     base.line <- exp(alpha) / (1 + exp(alpha))
     x1.effect <- exp(alpha + beta) / (1 + exp(alpha + beta))
     my.Diff   <- x1.effect - base.line
}
")

# Inits function
inits <- function(){ list(alpha=rlnorm(1), beta=rlnorm(1)) }

# Parameters to estimate
params <- c("alpha", "beta", "base.line", "x1.effect", "my.Diff")

# MCMC settings
na <- 5000
nb <- 10000
ni <- 50000
nc <- 3
nt <- 5

# Call JAGS, check convergence and summarize posteriors
out <- jags(bdata, inits, params, "logistic_regression_x1_June19_2023b.txt", 
            n.adapt  = na, n.thin = nt, n.chains = nc, 
            n.burnin = nb, n.iter = ni, parallel = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))  ;  traceplot(out)  ;  par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
print(out, dig = 3)
#               mean    sd     2.5%      50%    97.5% overlap0 f Rhat n.eff
# alpha       -0.947 0.047   -1.039   -0.947   -0.855    FALSE 1    1 10261
# beta         0.937 0.063    0.814    0.937    1.061    FALSE 1    1 24000
# base.line    0.280 0.009    0.261    0.279    0.298    FALSE 1    1 10330
# x1.effect    0.497 0.011    0.477    0.497    0.518    FALSE 1    1 24000
# my.Diff      0.218 0.014    0.190    0.218    0.246    FALSE 1    1 24000
# deviance  5787.494 1.994 5785.546 5786.884 5792.905    FALSE 1    1 23313
```

A `logistic regression` with three covariates and a `fixed intercept` with `glm`:

```
mylogitx1x2x3  <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogitx1x2x3)
# Call:
# glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = "binomial")
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -1.5235  -0.9677  -0.7161   1.1730   1.9674  
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -1.26456    0.10765 -11.747  < 2e-16 ***
# x1           0.96890    0.06439  15.048  < 2e-16 ***
# x2           0.36282    0.03945   9.198  < 2e-16 ***
# x3          -0.88179    0.11170  -7.894 2.92e-15 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 6012.4  on 4499  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 5637.4  on 4496  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 5645.4
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

A `logistic regression` with three covariates and a `fixed intercept` with `JAGS`:

```
y <- as.numeric(y)
n <- length(y)

str(bdata <- list(y = y, x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3, n = length(y)))

# Specify model in BUGS language
cat(file = "logistic_regression_x1x2x3_June19_2023b.txt","
model {

     # Priors
     alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
     beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
     beta2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
     beta3 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)

     # Likelihood
     for (i in 1:n) {
          y[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 1)  # Note p before N.  Here N = 1
          logit(p[i]) <- alpha + beta1 * x1[i] + beta2 * x2[i] + beta3 * x3[i]
     }

     # Derived quantities
     base.line       <- exp(alpha) / (1 + exp(alpha))
     beta1.effect    <- exp(alpha + beta1) / (1 + exp(alpha + beta1))
     beta1.base.Diff <- beta1.effect - base.line
}
")

# Inits function
inits <- function(){ list(alpha=rlnorm(1), beta1=rlnorm(1), beta2=rlnorm(1), beta3=rlnorm(1)) }

# Parameters to estimate
params <- c("alpha", "beta1", "beta2", "beta3", "base.line", "beta1.effect", "beta1.base.Diff")

# MCMC settings
na <- 5000
nb <- 10000
ni <- 50000
nc <- 3
nt <- 5

# Call JAGS, check convergence and summarize posteriors
out <- jags(bdata, inits, params, "logistic_regression_x1x2x3_June19_2023b.txt", 
            n.adapt  = na, n.thin = nt, n.chains = nc, 
            n.burnin = nb, n.iter = ni, parallel = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))  ;  traceplot(out)  ;  par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
print(out, dig = 3)
#                     mean    sd     2.5%      50%    97.5% overlap0 f Rhat n.eff
# alpha             -1.265 0.108   -1.477   -1.264   -1.054    FALSE 1    1 24000
# beta1              0.970 0.064    0.843    0.970    1.096    FALSE 1    1 24000
# beta2              0.363 0.039    0.285    0.363    0.440    FALSE 1    1 24000
# beta3             -0.884 0.112   -1.103   -0.884   -0.663    FALSE 1    1 23308
# base.line          0.221 0.019    0.186    0.220    0.258    FALSE 1    1 24000
# beta1.effect       0.427 0.026    0.378    0.427    0.478    FALSE 1    1 24000
# beta1.base.Diff    0.206 0.015    0.177    0.206    0.236    FALSE 1    1 24000
# deviance        5641.413 2.849 5637.892 5640.777 5648.486    FALSE 1    1 24000
```

A `logistic regression` with three covariates and a `random intercept` with `glmer`:

```
# Fit the model using the glmer() function from the lme4 package.
glmmres = glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|id), family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(glmmres)
# Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
#  Family: binomial  ( logit )
# Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | id)
# 
#      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#   5222.4   5254.5  -2606.2   5212.4     4495 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.1377 -0.4912 -0.2851  0.5539  2.8469 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  id     (Intercept) 3.114    1.765   
# Number of obs: 4500, groups:  id, 1500
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -1.94548    0.16250 -11.972   <2e-16 ***
# x1           1.51867    0.13161  11.539   <2e-16 ***
# x2           0.56017    0.05115  10.951   <2e-16 ***
# x3          -1.41114    0.16063  -8.785   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#    (Intr) x1     x2    
# x1 -0.490              
# x2 -0.680  0.118       
# x3 -0.355 -0.102 -0.090
```

A `logistic regression` with three covariates and a `random intercept` with `JAGS`:

```
y <- as.numeric(y)

n <- length(y)
n

ngroups = max(id)
ngroups

length(unique(id))

str(bdata <- list(y = y, x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3, id = id, n = n, ngroups = ngroups))

# Specify model in BUGS language
cat(file = "logistic_regression_randomint_June19_2023b.txt","
model {

     # Priors
     beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
     beta2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
     beta3 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)

     for (i in 1:ngroups){      
          alpha.int[i] ~ dnorm(mu.int, tau.int) # Random intercepts
     }

     mu.int ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)                   # Mean hyperparameter for random intercepts
     tau.int <- 1 / (sigma.int * sigma.int)
     sigma.int ~ dunif(0, 100)                  # SD hyperparameter for random intercepts

     # Likelihood
     for (i in 1:n) {
          y[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 1)
          logit(p[i]) <- beta1 * x1[i] + beta2 * x2[i] + beta3 * x3[i] + alpha.int[id[i]]
     }

}
")

# Inits function
inits <- function(){ list(beta1=rnorm(1,1,1), beta2=rnorm(1,1,1), beta3=rnorm(1,1,1),
                          alpha.int=rnorm(ngroups,0,2), mu.int = rnorm(1,0,1), sigma.int = rlnorm(1)) }

# Parameters to estimate
params <- c("beta1", "beta2", "beta3", "alpha.int", "mu.int", "sigma.int")

# MCMC settings
na <- 5000
nb <- 10000
ni <- 50000
nc <- 3
nt <- 5

# Call JAGS, check convergence and summarize posteriors
out <- jags(bdata, inits, params, "logistic_regression_randomint_June19_2023b.txt", 
            n.adapt  = na, n.thin = nt, n.chains = nc, 
            n.burnin = nb, n.iter = ni, parallel = TRUE)
print(out, dig = 3)

JAGS output for model 'logistic_regression_randomint_June19_2023b.txt', generated by jagsUI.
Estimates based on 3 chains of 50000 iterations,
adaptation = 5000 iterations (sufficient),
burn-in = 10000 iterations and thin rate = 5,
yielding 24000 total samples from the joint posterior. 
MCMC ran in parallel for 9.617 minutes at time 2023-06-19 20:12:43.

                    mean     sd     2.5%      50%    97.5% overlap0     f  Rhat n.eff
beta1              1.560  0.142    1.289    1.558    1.847    FALSE 1.000 1.000 16743
beta2              0.581  0.052    0.481    0.580    0.682    FALSE 1.000 1.000 11090
beta3             -1.464  0.165   -1.785   -1.463   -1.139    FALSE 1.000 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1]      -4.234  1.350   -7.104   -4.148   -1.817    FALSE 1.000 1.000 12433
alpha.int[2]      -4.292  1.330   -7.171   -4.208   -1.929    FALSE 1.000 1.000 24000
alpha.int[3]      -1.394  1.143   -3.566   -1.420    0.962     TRUE 0.888 1.000 11586
alpha.int[4]      -3.908  1.374   -6.847   -3.817   -1.431    FALSE 0.999 1.000 24000
alpha.int[5]      -1.477  1.159   -3.699   -1.500    0.900     TRUE 0.901 1.000 24000
alpha.int[6]      -1.368  1.118   -3.506   -1.394    0.919     TRUE 0.892 1.000 24000
alpha.int[7]      -1.579  1.135   -3.759   -1.610    0.769     TRUE 0.918 1.000 24000
alpha.int[8]      -3.933  1.367   -6.876   -3.849   -1.498    FALSE 1.000 1.000 24000
alpha.int[9]      -2.240  1.155   -4.631   -2.203   -0.030    FALSE 0.977 1.000 24000
alpha.int[10]     -4.233  1.341   -7.097   -4.159   -1.804    FALSE 1.000 1.000 24000
...
...
...
alpha.int[1490]   -1.438  1.212   -3.970   -1.391    0.802     TRUE 0.892 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1491]   -0.415  1.114   -2.580   -0.421    1.833     TRUE 0.649 1.000  5321
alpha.int[1492]   -1.794  1.180   -4.249   -1.755    0.429     TRUE 0.944 1.000  8539
alpha.int[1493]   -3.443  1.457   -6.546   -3.357   -0.836    FALSE 0.996 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1494]   -3.211  1.520   -6.462   -3.102   -0.543    FALSE 0.993 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1495]   -1.711  1.182   -4.170   -1.668    0.507     TRUE 0.937 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1496]   -1.768  1.181   -4.251   -1.720    0.438     TRUE 0.940 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1497]    0.900  1.255   -1.381    0.833    3.584     TRUE 0.762 1.000  5779
alpha.int[1498]   -1.602  1.195   -4.092   -1.550    0.640     TRUE 0.919 1.000 24000
alpha.int[1499]    1.159  1.219   -1.077    1.092    3.757     TRUE 0.834 1.000 13215
alpha.int[1500]    1.245  1.228   -1.013    1.185    3.842     TRUE 0.852 1.000 12048
mu.int            -2.001  0.169   -2.334   -1.999   -1.673    FALSE 1.000 1.000 10148
sigma.int          1.989  0.101    1.796    1.987    2.193    FALSE 1.000 1.000 24000
deviance        3787.846 63.459 3665.297 3787.234 3916.085    FALSE 1.000 1.000 24000
```

I am not entirely sure the `random intercept` `JAGS` code is correct.  The distributions used for initial values might be less than ideal.  But I think this is the `fixed intercept` in `glmer`:

```
mu.int            -2.001  0.169
```

And I think this is the random intercept estimate returned by `glmer`:

```
sigma.int          1.989  0.101
```

Although, it is a bit different from: `1.765`.

**EDIT - June 21, 2023**

Below is `JAGS` code for a `Bayesian` `logistic regression model` with `random intercepts` and three covariates.  This code is based on code I located here:

http://www.joerg-gross.net/code_snippets.php

My `JAGS` code returns estimates essentially the same as the true values and very close to those returned by `glmer` in the `lme4` package.  Note that this `JAGS` code includes both a `fixed intercept` and `random intercepts`.  Note that the `mean` of the `random intercepts` is constrained to zero.  Note also that the `initial values` might not be ideal.  Apparently `JAGS` is robust to initial values and can specify them automatically.  I am not sure whether to use the `mean` or the `median` estimates.  In this case they are almost the same.  Here is the `R` code and the results at the bottom:

```
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/Bayesian_logistic_regression/')

# install.packages('runjags')
library(lme4)
library(coda)
library(runjags)

set.seed(1234)

# MODEL
# y = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 + ran.b0[cluster.i]
# ran.b0 = N(0, ran.SD)

# PARAMETERS
n.groups       <- 1500     # the number of groups
n_per_group    <-    3     # the number of observations in each group
ran.b0.SD      <-    2     # the SD   of the random intercept
ran.b0.mu      <-    0     # the mean of the random intercept
b0             <-   -2.0
b1             <-    1.5
b2             <-    0.5
b3             <-   -1.0


# DATA FRAME

n <- n.groups * n_per_group   # the number of observations in the data set

group.id <- rep(1:n.groups, each=n_per_group)
group.id

x1 <- c(rep(1, round(n/2)), rep(0, (n - round(n/2))))
x2 <- rep(c(1:3), n.groups)
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1)

# mwm: this is the data set except y is not yet determined.
my.data <- data.frame(group.id = group.id, x0 = 1, x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3, y = NA)
head(my.data)
tail(my.data)


# RANDOM PART
# for each group determine the random intercept
ran.b0 <- c()
for(j in 1:n.groups) {
    ran.b0 <- c(ran.b0, rnorm(1, ran.b0.mu, ran.b0.SD))
}

# repeat each group-specific random intercept value for each observation within that group
ran.b0 <- rep(ran.b0, each = n_per_group)


# FIXED PART
for(i in 1:n) {

     # mwm: create the linear predictor for each observation in the data set
     fixed1 <- b0 + b1 * x1[i] + b2 * x2[i] + b3 * x3[i]
     random1 <- ran.b0[i]

     z <- random1 + fixed1

     # mwm: determine the y for each observation in the data set
     p <- 1/(1+exp(-z)) 

     my.data$y[i] <- rbinom(1,1,p)    

}


# LMER MODEL
# mwm: use the glmer function to model estimate the parameters in the model.
freq.model <- glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|group.id), data=my.data, family='binomial')
summary(freq.model)

fixed.effects  <- fixef(freq.model)
fixed.effects

random.effects <- ranef(freq.model)
head(random.effects$group.id)

my.coef <- coef(freq.model)  # (fixed + random intercepts)
dim(my.coef$group.id)
head(my.coef$group.id)

my.est.intercepts <- (as.numeric(fixed.effects[1]) + 
                      as.numeric(unlist(random.effects$group.id)))
head(my.est.intercepts)

range(my.est.intercepts - my.coef$group.id[,1])


#####@@@@@
#####@@@@@


# JAGS

data_jags <- list (n = n, 
                   n.groups = n.groups,
                   group.id = group.id,
                   y = my.data$y,
                   x1 = x1,
                   x2 = x2,
                   x3 = x3)

# variables that need to be passed from R:
# y = dependent
# n = number of data points
# group.id = cluster index for random effect 1
# n.groups = number of groups for random effect 1 
# ran.b0.mu is mean set to zero –> assuming b0 in fixed model

# Specify model in BUGS language
cat(file = "logistic_regression_random_intercept_StackOverflow_June21_2023.txt","
model {

     for (i in 1:n) {

          y[i] ~ dbin(p.bound[i], 1)
          p.bound[i]  <- max(0, min(1, p[i]))
          logit(p[i]) <- y.hat[i]

          y.hat[i]    <- random1[i] + fixed[i]

          random1[i]  <- ran.b0[group.id[i]]
          fixed[i]    <- beta0 + beta1 * x1[i] + beta2 * x2[i] + beta3 * x3[i]

     }

     # set up random effects
     for (j in 1:n.groups) {
          ran.b0[j] ~ dnorm(ran.b0.mu, ran.b0.tau)
          ran.b0.hat[j] <- ran.b0.mu
     }

     ran.b0.mu  <- 0
     ran.b0.tau <- pow(ran.b0.SD, -2) 
     ran.b0.SD ~ dunif(0, 100)

     # priors for fixed effects
     beta0 ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
     beta1 ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
     beta2 ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
     beta3 ~ dnorm(0, .0001)

}

")


#####@@@@@
#####@@@@@

inits1 <- list(ran.b0.SD = runif(1, 0, 100), .RNG.name="base::Super-Duper")
inits1

inits2 <- list(ran.b0.SD = runif(1, 0, 100), .RNG.name="base::Wichmann-Hill")
inits2

set.seed(123)
iterations <- 10000
jags <- run.jags("logistic_regression_random_intercept_StackOverflow_June21_2023.txt",
                 data = data_jags,
                 monitor=c('beta0', 'beta1', 'beta2', 'beta3', 'ran.b0.mu', 'ran.b0.SD'), 
                 n.chains=2, method='parallel', inits=list(inits1,inits2),     
                 sample = iterations,
                 burnin = round(iterations/4),
                 adapt  = round(iterations/10))

jags_summary <- print(jags)
jags_summary
#             Lower95    Median   Upper95       Mean         SD Mode       MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff     AC.10     psrf
# beta0     -2.363160 -2.033430 -1.664440 -2.0345681 0.17783558   NA 0.008716191     4.9   416 0.6492038 1.005197
# beta1      1.315480  1.607610  1.886100  1.6075509 0.14626945   NA 0.004581815     3.1  1019 0.3782639 1.000064
# beta2      0.387548  0.491456  0.594047  0.4919273 0.05235626   NA 0.001738343     3.3   907 0.4179176 1.002174
# beta3     -1.345870 -1.031850 -0.708995 -1.0308296 0.16366954   NA 0.004215616     2.6  1507 0.2261466 1.004994
# ran.b0.mu  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0000000 0.00000000    0          NA      NA    NA        NA       NA
# ran.b0.SD  1.828570  2.032160  2.226890  2.0327927 0.10139411   NA 0.003645367     3.6   774 0.4699476 1.001840


# True parameter values
# b0             <-   -2.0
# b1             <-    1.5
# b2             <-    0.5
# b3             <-   -1.0
# ran.b0.mu      <-    0     # the mean of the random intercept
# ran.b0.SD      <-    2     # the SD   of the random intercept


summary(freq.model)
# Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
#  Family: binomial  ( logit )
# Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | group.id)
#    Data: my.data
# 
#      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#   5256.3   5288.3  -2623.1   5246.3     4495 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -1.9913 -0.4881 -0.2796  0.5445  2.7589 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  group.id (Intercept) 3.293    1.815   
# Number of obs: 4500, groups:  group.id, 1500
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -1.99262    0.16545 -12.043   <2e-16 ***
# x1           1.57102    0.13470  11.663   <2e-16 ***
# x2           0.47534    0.05046   9.420   <2e-16 ***
# x3          -0.97992    0.15757  -6.219    5e-10 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#    (Intr) x1     x2    
# x1 -0.501              
# x2 -0.671  0.104       
# x3 -0.394 -0.064 -0.045
```

Comment: This is fine, although I'll point out that (1) simulating is **way** easier than estimating in this case and (2) `lme4` will let you simulate response values based on a formula and specified parameters [and a data frame encoding covariates and grouping variables], although it's not as transparent  as rolling your own ...